# font-size в зависимости от длины самого текста

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Есть блок фиксированной ширины(пусть 500px), меняя длину текста в нем,нужно чтобы шрифт в нем постоянно был "подогнанным" к ширине родителя и всегда в одну строку. Максимальный размер 40px. 
p.s. заказчик извращенец попался =)

Comment: А что делать в случае, если текст == 1 символ? А если 501? Так-то подогнать можно, но в известных пределах.

Comment: Пардон забыл добавить условие. Обновил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть [готовые решения](http://trentwalton.com/2012/06/19/fluid-type/). Я в свое время делал такой вариант для номеров телефонов:

```js
    // текст по ширине родителя
    $(".resizeble-font").each(function ()
    {
        var length = $(this).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\(|\)|8-/gm, '').length,
            size = $(this).width() / length * parseFloat($(this).data('ratio'));
        if ($(this).find('a').size())
        {
            $(this).find('a').css('font-size', size + 'px');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).css('font-size', size + 'px');
        }
    });
```

```css
.resizeble-font {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resizeble-font" data-ratio="1.9" style="width: 100px">
    тест тест тест тест тест 84646 фцвфцв
</div>
<div class="resizeble-font" data-ratio="1.9" style="width: 200px">
    тест тест тест 4
</div>
<div class="resizeble-font" data-ratio="1.9" style="width: 500px">
    тест 654
</div>
```

В моем варианте `data-ratio="1.9"` меняется для разных шрифтов. Соответственно вам можно добавить проверку на макс. размер шрифта в 40 пикс

Answer (score 1):

Вся суть идеи моего решения сводится к тому, чтобы измерять ширину данного текста с помощью рендеринга в невидимом элементе с разными размерами шрифтов и сравнивать длину текста с максимально возможной.

Из списка допустимых значений выбирается наиболее подходящее, либо минимально возможное, если не подходит ни один из размеров шрифта.

В этом случае сработает fallback на css и к тексту добавится многоточие.

Под спойлером написанный мной плагин для jQuery с комментариями по коду.

Недостатки:

- у плагина нет опций. Базовые значения захардкожены
- работает только с целочисленными значениями в **пикселях**

```js
$.fn.fitTextToLine = function() {
  // Создаем элемент для измерения ширины текста.
  var textMeasure = $("<div/>").css({
    'id': 'text-measure',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'line-height': 'normal',
    'visibility': 'hidden',
    'width': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto',
    'white-space': 'nowrap',
    'pointer-events': 'none'
  });

  // Вставляем его в документ, если его там до этого не было.
  if ($('#text-measure').length === 0) {
    $('body').prepend(textMeasure);
  }

  // Перебираем элементы, для которых вызвана функция
  this.each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    // Максимальная ширина элемента
    var maxWidth = element.width();
    var text = element.text().trim();
    // Минимально допустимый размер шрифта
    var minFontSize = 14;
    // Максимально допустимый размер шрифта
    var maxFontSize = 40;
    var availableFontSizes = [];

    // Генерируем список допустимых размеров шрифтов
    for (var i = minFontSize; i <= maxFontSize; i++) {
      availableFontSizes.push(i);
    }

    // Устанавливаем размер шрифта измерителя как у исследуемого элемента
    textMeasure.css('font-size', element.css('font-size'));

    // Устанавливаем допустимую погрешность в ширине текста
    // Латинская "M" выбрана неспроста.
    // Основание: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)
    var measureTolerance = textMeasure.text('M').width();
    var measureToleranceRange = [];

    // Генерируем границы допустимой ширины текста
    for (var j = (maxWidth - measureTolerance); j <= maxWidth; j++) {
      measureToleranceRange.push(j);
    }

    // Измеряем ширину текста до модификаций
    var textWidth = textMeasure.text(text).width();

    // Проверяем, не лежит ли она в границах допустимой ширины
    if ($.inArray(textWidth, measureToleranceRange) !== -1) {
      // Лежит в границах допустимой ширины, дальше мерять не надо
      return;
    }

    // Функция рекурсивно проверяет все допустимые размеры шрифта
    // и выбирает наиболее подходящий.
    function recursiveMeasure(text, measure, fontSizes, toleranceRange) {
      // Случай, когда манипуляций остался один допустимый шрифт.
      // Его и возвращаем.
      if (fontSizes.length === 1) {
        return fontSizes[0];
      }

      // Берем элемент из середины массива с размерами шрифтов, чтобы ускорить обработку.
      var middleIndex = Math.ceil(fontSizes.length / 2);
      // Получаем максимальное допустимое значение ширины.
      var maxWidth = toleranceRange[toleranceRange.length - 1];

      // Устанавливаем размер шрифта измерителя.
      measure.css('font-size', fontSizes[middleIndex] + 'px');

      // Рассчитываем ширину текста для этого размера шрифта.
      var textWidth = measure.text(text).width();
      // Проверяем, превышена ли максимально допустимая ширина.
      var isMaxWidthExceeded = textWidth > maxWidth;

      // Отдельный случай: когда осталось два шрифта для обработки.
      if (fontSizes.length === 2) {
        // Если превышена максимально допустимая ширина текста,
        // то мы возвращаем минимально возможный размер шрифта.
        return isMaxWidthExceeded ? fontSizes[0] : fontSizes[middleIndex];
      }

      // Если превышена максимально допустимая ширина текста,
      // то мы обрабатываем левую половину массива допустимых размеров шрифта.
      // Там размеры шрифта меньше.
      if (isMaxWidthExceeded) {
        return recursiveMeasure(
          text,
          measure,
          fontSizes.slice(0, middleIndex),
          toleranceRange
        );
      }

      // Если максимально допустимая ширина текста НЕ превышена,
      // то мы обрабатываем правую половину массива допустимых размеров шрифта.
      // Там размеры шрифта больше.
      return recursiveMeasure(
        text,
        measure,
        fontSizes.slice(middleIndex),
        toleranceRange
      );
    }

    // Получаем максимально подходящий размер шрифта.
    var fontSize = recursiveMeasure(
      text,
      textMeasure,
      availableFontSizes,
      measureToleranceRange
    );

    // Корректируем стили элемента.
    element.css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
  });

  // Сбрасываем измеритель.
  textMeasure.css('font-size', '');
  textMeasure.text('');

  return this;
};

// Пример вызова
$('.text').fitTextToLine();
```

```css
.text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.w1 {
  width: 300px;
}
.w2 {
  width: 250px;
}
.w3 {
  width: 200px;
}
.w4 {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="text w1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="text w2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<div class="text w3">Lorem.</div>
<div class="text w4">Lorem ipsum dolo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В этом коде ще нужно добавлять font-weight элемента тк она тоже на ширину буквы влияет

```js
$.fn.fitTextToLine = function() {
  // Создаем элемент для измерения ширины текста.
  var textMeasure = $("<div/>").css({
    'id': 'text-measure',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'line-height': 'normal',
    'visibility': 'hidden',
    'width': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto',
    'white-space': 'nowrap',
    'pointer-events': 'none'
  });

  // Вставляем его в документ, если его там до этого не было.
  if ($('#text-measure').length === 0) {
    $('body').prepend(textMeasure);
  }

  // Перебираем элементы, для которых вызвана функция
  this.each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    // Максимальная ширина элемента
    var maxWidth = element.width();
    var text = element.text().trim();
    // Минимально допустимый размер шрифта
    var minFontSize = 14;
    // Максимально допустимый размер шрифта
    var maxFontSize = 40;
    var availableFontSizes = [];

    // Генерируем список допустимых размеров шрифтов
    for (var i = minFontSize; i <= maxFontSize; i++) {
      availableFontSizes.push(i);
    }

    // Устанавливаем размер шрифта измерителя как у исследуемого элемента
    textMeasure.css('font-size', element.css('font-size'));

    // Устанавливаем допустимую погрешность в ширине текста
    // Латинская "M" выбрана неспроста.
    // Основание: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)
    var measureTolerance = textMeasure.text('M').width();
    var measureToleranceRange = [];

    // Генерируем границы допустимой ширины текста
    for (var j = (maxWidth - measureTolerance); j <= maxWidth; j++) {
      measureToleranceRange.push(j);
    }

    // Измеряем ширину текста до модификаций
    var textWidth = textMeasure.text(text).width();

    // Проверяем, не лежит ли она в границах допустимой ширины
    if ($.inArray(textWidth, measureToleranceRange) !== -1) {
      // Лежит в границах допустимой ширины, дальше мерять не надо
      return;
    }

    // Функция рекурсивно проверяет все допустимые размеры шрифта
    // и выбирает наиболее подходящий.
    function recursiveMeasure(text, measure, fontSizes, toleranceRange) {
      // Случай, когда манипуляций остался один допустимый шрифт.
      // Его и возвращаем.
      if (fontSizes.length === 1) {
        return fontSizes[0];
      }

      // Берем элемент из середины массива с размерами шрифтов, чтобы ускорить обработку.
      var middleIndex = Math.ceil(fontSizes.length / 2);
      // Получаем максимальное допустимое значение ширины.
      var maxWidth = toleranceRange[toleranceRange.length - 1];

      // Устанавливаем размер шрифта измерителя.
      measure.css('font-size', fontSizes[middleIndex] + 'px');

      // Рассчитываем ширину текста для этого размера шрифта.
      var textWidth = measure.text(text).width();
      // Проверяем, превышена ли максимально допустимая ширина.
      var isMaxWidthExceeded = textWidth > maxWidth;

      // Отдельный случай: когда осталось два шрифта для обработки.
      if (fontSizes.length === 2) {
        // Если превышена максимально допустимая ширина текста,
        // то мы возвращаем минимально возможный размер шрифта.
        return isMaxWidthExceeded ? fontSizes[0] : fontSizes[middleIndex];
      }

      // Если превышена максимально допустимая ширина текста,
      // то мы обрабатываем левую половину массива допустимых размеров шрифта.
      // Там размеры шрифта меньше.
      if (isMaxWidthExceeded) {
        return recursiveMeasure(
          text,
          measure,
          fontSizes.slice(0, middleIndex),
          toleranceRange
        );
      }

      // Если максимально допустимая ширина текста НЕ превышена,
      // то мы обрабатываем правую половину массива допустимых размеров шрифта.
      // Там размеры шрифта больше.
      return recursiveMeasure(
        text,
        measure,
        fontSizes.slice(middleIndex),
        toleranceRange
      );
    }

    // Получаем максимально подходящий размер шрифта.
    var fontSize = recursiveMeasure(
      text,
      textMeasure,
      availableFontSizes,
      measureToleranceRange
    );

    // Корректируем стили элемента.
    element.css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
  });

  // Сбрасываем измеритель.
  textMeasure.css('font-size', '');
  textMeasure.text('');

  return this;
};

// Пример вызова
$('.text').fitTextToLine();
```

```css
.text {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.w1 {
  width: 300px;
}
.w2 {
  width: 250px;
}
.w3 {
  width: 200px;
}
.w4 {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div class="text w1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<div class="text w2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<div class="text w3">Lorem.</div>
<div class="text w4">Lorem ipsum dolo</div>
```